# Check array for duplicate values if cookies aren't set, don't check if cookies are set

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, socket.io

I'm working on a chatroom page where you first set your username and it sets the username value inside cookies. after this it loads different input boxes where you can send messages from in realtime. At this point you can reload the page and it will give you a pop-up which will display a welcome back message with the name value saved inside the cookies, which will also just set it as the username again and load the chatting page.

The problem is that I want to be able to prevent multiple duplicates of a name to be set from the username setting input field, but allow the username be set multiple times inside the array via cookies.

this function sets the original username:

```
//index.html
function setUsername() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("name");
    var txtboxval = textbox.value;
    if(textbox.value.length <= 20 && textbox.value.length >= 4){
      socket.emit('setUsername', document.getElementById('name').value);
      setCookie("username", txtboxval, 30);
      socket.on('userExists', function(data) {

      });
    }
    else{
        alert("The name has to be at least 4 characters long");
        return false;
      }
    };
```

and these two set it on cookie load:

```
  //index.html
  function setUsername2() {
    var nimi = getCookie('username');
    socket.emit('setUsername', nimi);
  }

  function checkCookie() {
      var user = getCookie("username");
      if (user != "") {
          alert("Welcome again " + user);
          setUsername2();
          document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="messagebox"><input type = "text" id = "message" placeholder = "Write your message here">\
          <button type = "button" id="sending" name = "button" onclick = "sendMessage()">Send</button></div>\
          <div id = "message-container"></div></div>';
      }
    }
```

now this here actually sets the username into the array where it digs it from on the index.html page:

```
  //app.js
  users = [];
  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('an user connected');
    console.log(users);
    socket.on('setUsername', function(data) {
      console.log(data);

        users.push(data);
        socket.emit('userSet', {username: data});
        console.log(users);
  });
```

I would like this piece of code to run when first setting the username, but not when it loads from cookies:

```
//app.js
if(users.indexOf(data) > -1) {
          socket.emit('userExists', data + ' Username is already taken.');
        } else {
          users.push(data);
          socket.emit('userSet', {username: data});
          console.log(users);
        }
```

Is there something I'm missing on why I can't get it to work as I would like it to? If something is unclear please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get this done triggering your `'setUsername'` using an object `{name: string, cookie: boolean}` instead of the username only, like i did here:

```
function setUsername() {
  var textbox = document.getElementById("name");
  var txtboxval = textbox.value;
  if(textbox.value.length <= 20 && textbox.value.length >= 4){
    socket.emit('setUsername', {name: document.getElementById('name').value, cookie: false});
    setCookie("username", txtboxval, 30);
    socket.on('userExists', function(data) {
      // ########## you could add your 'already taken'-message here. :) ##########
      console.log(data);
      document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;"; 
      // this 'deletes' the cookie.
    });
  } else {
    alert("The name has to be at least 4 characters long");
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

```
function setUsername2() {
  var nimi = getCookie('username');
  socket.emit('setUsername', {name: nimi, cookie: true});
}

function checkCookie() {
  var user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
    setUsername2();
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="wrapper"><div class="messagebox"><input type = "text" id = "message" placeholder = "Write your message here">\
    <button type = "button" id="sending" name = "button" onclick = "sendMessage()">Send</button></div>\
    <div id = "message-container"></div></div>';
  }
}
```

---

```
users = [];
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('an user connected');
  console.log(users);
  socket.on('setUsername', function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    if(!data.cookie && users.indexOf(data.name) > -1) {
      socket.emit('userExists', data.name + ' Username is already taken.');
    } else {
      users.push(data.name);
      socket.emit('userSet', {username: data.name});
      console.log(users);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This gives me reference errors when trying to set the name, "Uncaught ReferenceError: setUsername is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick " and "(index):291 Uncaught ReferenceError: checkCookie is not defined
    at onload " also it says that somewhere in the setUsername function there's a missing ) I can't find it though.

Comment: SyntaxErrors are fixed now. My fault. :)

Comment: ah :), I tried after syntax fixes and this actually works, 1 more thing, where in there could I give a message that would say that the name is already in use?

Comment: inside the `socket.on('setUsername' […]` function, under or above the `socket.emit('userExists', data.name + ' Username is already taken.');`

Comment: actually shouldn't that socket.emit already display a comment as such?

Comment: ah :) i see, you only have to display the `data` inside your `function setUsername()`s `socket.on('userExists' […]`

Comment: edited my answer, now the comment is at the right position.

Comment: furthermore, i think at this event you should clear the cookie too.

Comment: I tried adding `socket.emit('userExists', data.name + ' Username is already taken.');` inside the `socket.on` doesn't seem to display anything, by clearing you mean calling `function delete_cookie( name ) {
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
  }` inside it yes?

Comment: adding `socket.emit('userExists', data.name + ' Username is already taken.');` only triggers the 'userExists' Event again. inside the event you have to outpoot the `'data'` for example using `console.log`, `alert` or whatever you want. :)

Comment: calling the delete Cookie function like `'deleteCookie(getCookie(txtboxval));` could be a cleaner solution. or set the cookie after checking if the username is taken inside the `else` using something like `if(!data.cookie) setCookie('username', data.name, 30);`

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the 2nd one,  if I call it inside the `else` it wouldn't work properly would it since if would never call for it unless the if requirements were not filled would it?

Comment: take a look at my edited answer. I've changed it to setting the cookie after checking if the username already exists. :)

Comment: Ah, that shouldn't work due to the cookies being defined in a different file than the `socket.on('setUsername', function(data) { ` function, cookies are set in "Index.html" while socket.on is set in "app.js", attempting to set an username simply crashes the whole site due to `setCookie()` not being  defined

Comment: for that you only have to copy the `setCookie()` function into your app.js. And if you don't use the function in the index.html anymore you could remove it there, too.

Comment: still crashes the whole process when attempting to set the name, probably due to how the function is built, it gives this error `document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined` , the `setCookie()` is built in  like this in the file for reference `function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30*1000));
      var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }`

Comment: okay, changed my answer to the first solution by 'deleting' the cookie on the 'userExists'-event

Comment: Tried it just now, this works, I don't see any more issues being there so thank you very much I've been stuck on this problem for days! Thanks a huge bunch! I will award the bounty to you once it becomes available :)

Answer (score 0):

If i got it right, and you want to distinct two activities - setting username from cookie and setting username from input#name -, so you just have to emit *userExists* with some additional data, with some flag, like *cookie* (which will mean that you're setting the value from cookie) or *user_input* (which will mean that you're setting the value from the input field), like this:

```
socket.emit('userSet', {username: data.name, user_input: true});
```

Comment: Mind giving an example on the part on how I should do it? I don't exactly understand how I would build the syntax.

Comment: @Veraen, first part: you have 2 ways of setting cookies - from input and from cookies. Second part: you catch *userSet* event and extract value from it. But you can't say where did the event come from. So you have to put additional data in it, just to be able to say where did it come from: from input or from cookies. Now, when you can distinct username sources, you decide if you want to emit *userExists* or no. That's it!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I've got my solution from J. Sadi's answer.